# Why is Independence Day "The Fourth of July" but the day after is "July the Fifth"

Tags: etymology, american-english

US english seems to constantly be "Month Day" but when talking about Independence Day it switches to "Day of Month".

Comment: I don’t think you’re working with a large enough sample size.

Comment: The Fourth of July is a national holiday, and the use of the term has developed over time.  It's the name of something, not just a date.

Comment: This bothers me. The fourth of July is not a holiday. Independence Day is the holiday, and the fourth of July is when it occurs. People don't go around saying *Merry 25th of December*, or *Happy 1st of January*, do they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the formulas "<month> <ordinal numeral>" and "the <ordinal numeral> of <month>" are both fairly common, and have both been fairly common since the founding of the Republic, it used to be that the formula "the <ordinal numeral> of <month>" was more common, whereas the formula "<month> <ordinal numeral>" is more common today. See, for example, [these Google Ngram Viewer results (for August 2nd)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=August+second%2Csecond+of+August%2CAugust+2nd%2C2nd+of+August&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1776&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CAugust%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BAugust%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAugust%20Second%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAUGUST%20SECOND%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecond%20of%20August%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAugust%202nd%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C2nd%20of%20August%3B%2Cc0). Since "the Fourth of July" effectively functions as a name for the holiday, it's not too surprising that it would retain the old formula. (That said, "July 4th" is also often used as a name for the holiday — I don't think anyone would blink at "the July 4th weekend" or "July Fourth observed" — so it's also probably shifting over time, just more slowly.)